# What is the difference between Workers and Threads in Puma

Tags: multithreading, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

What is the difference between a puma worker and a puma thread in context of a heroku dyno?

What I know (please correct me if I am wrong):

- Thin is not concurrent, so a web process can only do one request at a time
- In unicorn, I know I can have several unicorn workers in one process to add concurrency.

But in puma there is threads and workers.. Isn't a worker a thread inside the puma process?

Can I use more workers/threads to add web concurrency in Heroku?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As the other answer states, this [Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) is pretty good with explanations of certain configuration items.

However if you need to tune your application on Heroku, or anywhere, then it pays to know how things work.

I think you are almost correct when you say "a worker is a thread inside the puma process", I believe a worker is an operating system level process forked from puma which then can use threads internally.

As far as I understand - puma will fork its operating system process however many times you set via `workers` configuration to respond to http requests. This gives you parallelism in terms of handling multiple requests but this will usually take up more memory as it will 'copy' your application code for each worker.

Each puma worker will then use multiple threads within its OS process depending on the `threads` configuration. These add concurrency by allowing the puma process to respond to multiple requests itself so that if one thread is blocked, ie processing a request, it can handle a new request with another thread. As stated, this requires your entire application to be threadsafe so that, for example any global configuration from one request does not 'leak' into another.

You would tune puma so that the number of workers was adequate for the number of CPUs and memory available and then tune the threads dependant on how much you would want to saturate the host running your application and how your application behaves - more does not always equal faster/more request throughput.

Answer (score 18):

This is a big area and I am not an expert, however...

Puma can spawn many workers, and each worker can use many threads to process the request.

Unicorn does not have threads as far as I know, it just has the worker model.

If you use threads though, you need to make sure that your code is thread safe. This means Rails, any gem you rely on, and your own code.

For maximum performance, you might also want to look into [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) or [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) which have proper thread support. MRI is restricted by its GIL.

There is a [good article on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) which explains how Puma uses workers and threads. You should probably read that and ignore me :)

Comment: "...each worker can use many threads to process the request" isn't correct. It would only ever use one thread per request. (unless your app code manually spawns threads). If can server multiple requests within the same process using multiple threads though.

Answer (score 13):

I just want to emphasize the most important line of the Heroku/Puma article that was referenced here:

> Rails maintains its own database connection pool, with a new pool
>   created for each worker process. Threads within a worker will operate
>   on the same pool.

It states that each Worker will have its own Pool. However:

> Threads within a worker will operate on the same pool.

This is very important to understand. If a Puma Worker utilizes 5 threads per worker, then the database.yml must be configured to a connection pool of 5, since each thread could possibly establish a database connection.

Since each Worker is spawned by a system fork(), the new worker will have its own set of 5 threads to work with, and thus for the new Rails instance created, the database.yml will still be set to a connection pool of 5.

Now the database.yml connection pool and your actual database pool are two different things. The TOTAL connections to your database will need to use a specific formula that the Heroku docs mention:

> A good formula for determining the number of connections each application will require is to multiply the RAILS_MAX_THREADS by the WEB_CONCURRENCY.

What this means is if you are using 2 Workers, each with 5 threads, then 2 * 5 = 10, so your database must be configured to accept 10 concurrent connections.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer the question from the perspective of someone that is at the beginning of the threads understanding journey:

---

1. A worker is a new OS instance of that Rails application with all of the application's code and ENV variables and with its own separate RAM.
2. A worker can be configured to have multiple threads. It is important to know that each of these threads will share the same RAM and state of ENV variables as the other threads of this particular worker.
3. A worker can work on one thread at a time so when the current thread is stuck doing some processing, that worker will start working on a new thread.
4. Given the fact that the state of the variables is shared between all threads, this can cause the first thread to have changed a mutable data structure the second thread would have required to be in the initial state.

Making your code thread-safe can often be complicated. Besides the solutions proposed in the other answers, I would also say that it's a good idea to look into [Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-6.0#:%7E:text=Mutex%20is%20a%20synchronization%20primitive,type%20implements%20the%20IDisposable%20interface.) and to understand the way your DB is dealing with threads. For that, I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280743/what-is-the-difference-between-workers-and-threads-in-puma) Postgresql SO answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Worker :-**

- A worker is a separate instance of the Puma server and its running in its own process. Each worker is capable of handling multiple requests in parallel using multiple threads. For example, when a new request comes in Puma master process distributes the request to one of the worker processes, and then the worker process handles the request using one of its threads.

**Thread :-**

- Thread is a lightweight unit of execution within a worker process. Each worker process can have multiple threads but each thread is capable of handling a single request at a time.